# jQuery How to change text on second element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change h1 text on h1 element on second div (parent2) when click button with jQuery. Thanks!

```
<div id="parent1">
  <h1 class="child">Hello World</h1>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
  <h1 class="child">Hello World</h1>
</div>
<div id="parent3">
  <h1 class="child">Hello World</h1>
</div>

<button>Change</button>
```

Comment: `$('#parent2 .child').text('your text')`.

Comment: @Kinduser You could add a comment that solves the user question more than flat code to your answer and if supposed to be an answer you can include it as answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you want a solution based on the position, aka *first h1 and second div*, and not based on classes and IDs, then you have :

```
 $('div:nth-child(2) > h1').text('your text');
```

But this is just to show how it's done to select by position, @Kinduser's answer is preferable.

And to trigger the button click, refers to @splitwire's indication:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
   $('div:nth-child(2) > h1').text('your text');
});
```

```js
$('#example button').first().click(function () {
  $('#example div:nth-child(2) > h1').text('your text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"> 
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
  <button>Change</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that this is _just to show_ how it can be selected using selectors without classes, but **should not be used as is**. As @MariusTodoran pointed out, `$('button').on('click', ...)` will bind all button in the page, and selectors on solely div will match all divs. This should not be the best answer, but note for information only.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon *Kind user*'s answer:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    //kind user's code here//
    $('#parent2 .child').text('text'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<div id="parent1">
    <h1 class="child">Hello World</h1>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
    <h1 class="child">Hello World</h1>
</div>
<div id="parent3">
    <h1 class="child">Hello World</h1>
</div>

<button id="changeTextButton">Change</button>
```

And the JavaScript part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#changeTextButton').click(function () {
                $('#parent2 .child').text('Custom text');
            });
        });
```

**EDIT**: The above answers with

```
 $('button').on('click', function () {
```

will create the same event for each button on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like that.

```
 $('button').on('click', function() {
        $('#parent2 .child').html('some text here'); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div:nth-child(2) > h1').text('your new text here');
$('div:nth-child(2)) //2 is the index no of div you can change as you required. like 1
&nbsp;
```